# Mongoid Versioning Confusion :)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

:) Got a new task and struggle a bit. I need to implement versioning in my rails apps. So I tried few gems like mongoid history, mongoid papertrail, and the most simple Mongoid:Versioning. Would like to use the last one, just can't find proper api docks and don't know how to lets say reverse from version 5 to version 2. You have something like versions.count, versions.first, versions.last, versions.where...... and that's about it :) Thank you for any advice or help! :)

Comment: I just know it's very simple task and makes me feel a bit dumb :) And second of all - in general I'm a very happy person :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given you have an article that changes its versions, to revert:

```
article = Article.find("the-id")
article.attributes = article.versions.where(version: 0).first.attributes
article.save
```

Note that this will just put a new versions in the list of versions, with this at the top of the stack.

To list all versions:

```
article.versions
```

To show a particular revision:

```
article.versions.where(version: 4).first
```

Comment: did it in almost exact way. Thank you